# Java split sentence at full stop whitespace?

Tags: java, regex, punctuation

I need to split a text file into individual sentences, but at the moment it also splits decimal points. How do i split at the point where there is a full stop then whitespace.

Comment: With the regex: `"\\.\s"` But this is for any whitespace. If you need a specific whitespace, replace `\s` with the appropriate character.

Comment: Well, just split on dot followed by space? Doesn't seem like you need a regex for that.

Comment: it splits all spaces then, meaning you cannot ever split a full sentence

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include `.` in result after split you can try splitting on each whitespaces (`\\s`) which has full stop `[.]` before it.

```
yourString.split("(?<=[.])\\s+");
```

DEMO

```
for (String s:"ab. cd 1.3 ef. gh".split("(?<=[.])\\s+"))
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
ab.
cd 1.3 ef.
gh
```

---

If you don't want to include `.` in result then skip [look-behind mechanism](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) and use `[.]\\s+`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex into the split so that it doesn't pick anything between digits. This regex means a full-stop not followed by a digit.

```
\\.(?!\\d)
```

Example:

```
String line = "this a. sample 100.100 test.line.";
String []sentences = line.trim().split("\\.(?!\\d)");
```

Output:

```
this a
 sample 100.100 test
line
```

You may want to improve this by adding optional `\\s*` around the splits.

Comment: Is there any real difference to using `"\\.[^0-9]"`?

Comment: @AntonH yes. Using your regex it will remove the `.X` from the following example `sample.X test`

Comment: that didnt do anything other than give random results

Answer (score 0):

```
String parts[] = str.split("\\. " );
```

should work

Comment: doesnt work, splits at any whitespace then meaning each word is then treated as a sentence

Comment: i have that now working, i would i include a condition for an ! or a ? also